# Radio buttons in Hobo Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hobo

How can I use radio buttons in a form in Hobo Rails? I want a gender field with two options "Male" and "Female". If I use the default enum_string type it creates drop down select instead of radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hobo does not currently support radio buttons.  You have to do them yourself.
There is a half complete tag defined in [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/hobousers/browse_thread/thread/5036533490f144e6/da9dbc04597a7955?lnk=gst&q=radio#da9dbc04597a7955).